# How can I get a list of entities in NHibernate where the ParentId might refer to different tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm new to NHibernate so I'm sure that I'm just missing something fundamental.

I have an table called Issue that has a ParentId column.  The ParentId can refer to different tables (i.e. - Project or Customer, etc.)  How can I do that query in NHibernate so that I can show only the Issues that belong to Project.  Here is what I've tried.

```
            DetachedCriteria dCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Issue>("issue")
            .SetProjection(Projections.Property("ParentId"))
            .CreateAlias("Project", "project", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
            .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("issue.ParentId", "project.Id"))
            ;
        var issues = Session.CreateCriteria<Issue>("issue")
                .Add(Subqueries.Exists(dCriteria)).List<Issue>();
        return issues;
```

my mapping looks like this.  Notice I don't have any reference to the parent object because I don't know what it will be.

```
    <class name="Issue" table="dbo.Issue" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="Id">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <property name="ParentId" column="ParentId" />

    <property name="Name" />

    <property name="Description" />
```

### I would appreciate any guidance.

perhaps I should explain a little more.  I have a grid of all issues and I want to show a type column so we know what type of issue (project, etc.)  the column doesn't serve any other purpose than this one display so I don't believe it's valid to add it to the database.  In SQL it's easy enough to filter the data via the join or using Exists.  There must be a similar method in NHibernate so I don't have to loop through every Project for all it's issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a horrible design. You should at least use different columns for the relations or an other column to identify the type or the parent object.

If you do that, you will be able to map it cleanly with NHibernate.

If you can't for some reason, maybe an any-mapping is what you are looking for.

Comment: Generic statements like "that's a horrible design" aren't really productive to solving the problem.  it might help if you described what any-mapping does or is

Comment: @Steven, you can certainly look up `<any>` in the NHibernate docs.

Comment: Here's Ayende's overview of this feature: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/06/05/NHibernatesAssociationIsCool.aspx

Comment: Steven, well, it is horrible design when you can't distinguish the object types you are referring to! That WILL cause trouble and confusion!

Comment: The <any> was what I was looking for.  I'm new to this approach of mapping so was looking for guidance on how to accomplish.  In the past, I've avoided adding a 'Type' column because type can simply be filtered out with a database join, but it makes sense the way Ayende describes it in the post.  Thanks to Falcon AND UpTheCreek for your directions.

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't be using Foreign Key Ids directly in your objects - That's a data centric approach. With NHibernate you work with real objets or collections of real objects to represent the relationships.  Nhibernate takes care of the foreign Keys in your DB automatically
2. I would use an interface or base class to represent the different items that can be used as the parent if you really need to the Issue to have a link back to it's parent.  But probably you don't as you'll most likely be fetching e.g. a 'customer' and then iterating through the issues.
3. Assigned Ids are generally a bad
   idea.  Better to use something like
   HiLo or the the DBs Native
   generator.

For instance, your objects might look something like this:

```
public class Issue
{
   public int Id{ get; set; }
   public IHazIssues Parent { get; set; } //If you really need this
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : IHazIssues 
{
   public int Id{ get; set; }
   public IList<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
   public string NAme{ get; set; }
}

//If you don't need the parent mapping on Item you don't need this.
public interface IHazIssues 
{
   IList<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
}
```

etc...

Comment: I've added some additional info about what I'm trying to accomplish.  I get what you are trying to do here but it seems overly complex for the limited need I have (see additional comments above).

Comment: Yes, With this approach you can loop through all of the issues, and find out what they are attached to.  Sorry if this seems overly complex, but this is how you use NHibernate - Why are you using it if you want to take a data centric approach?